# Reading record at particular index from Linux Message Queue

Tags: linux, message-queue

I know that behavior of message queue is sequential but is there any way to read a particular record from Linux message queue ?

Like I want to pass *`index`* and *`msg queue id`* and I should get data/record present at that index.

For eg. If I have 100 records in a message queue and I want to read 23rd record then I can pass index as 23 and I should get record present at 23rd position by skipping first 22 records.

I tried using message type but it is also sequential.

Comment: If you can't hack something based on msgtype - you *can* specify what msgtype to read - then no.  It's a queue not an array and reading the queue will consume the record and throw the rest off anyway.  If you already know you are interested in msg #23 you probably have some other means of communication that you can use.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Actually I add msgtype depending on time. And after some time interval if there are any records present in queue they are taken care at end of day by some other process and that process reads records from same queue. So in reader process i need to skip some records

Comment: You aren't going to get random access out of this but msgtype is a long so can you work with that?  E.g. HHNNNNN where HH is 1-24 depending on hour and NNNNN is a sequence number.  With `msgrcv` you can specify msgtype as 1800000 and sequentially read the 6pm records from there.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the message index in "msgtyp" while sending the message. And while receiving the message specify the index you want to read in that "msgtyp". That way you will able to read specific index messages in the mesgqueue

```
struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;       /* use message type as a message index*/
    char mtext[1];    /* message data */
};
```